# Python Decoration - Keep the original function

Tags: python, decorator

Let **f** be a function.
In a simple decoration of **f**, **f** is replaced by wrapper(**f**).
What if I want to keep the original **f** (and)
define a new function **g** s.t. **g** = wrapper(**f**)
i.e. I want to not only wrapper(**f**), but also to keep **f** itself.

Can I do it using the @ notation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `g = decorator(f)` should work.

Comment: Your question contains the solution: `g = wrapper(f)`. Did you try it and did it not work?

Comment: Another question.
How can I delete stupid questions?

Answer (score 2):

By definition of a decorator, this code:

```
@wrapper
def f():
   ...
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
def f():
   ...

f = wrapper(f)
```

Which means that:

```
def f():
   ...

g = wrapper(f)
```

will do exactly what you want.